# Lollipop: Unwanted light menu on DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-styles

I have a very basic application with a DarkActionBar.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Now I am testing it on Android Lollipop. The action bar is dark, but the popup menu is light. This is not the case on previous android versions.

I tried this, but the effect was not as desired (dark text on dark background):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 21 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <!-- Will result in dark PopupMenu, but with dark text color (hard to read) -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

Is this a bug? How to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally:

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 21+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v21/styles.xml on API 21+ devices.
-->

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 21 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F3F3F3</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F3F3F3</item>
</style>

<!-- style the overflow menu -->
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#303030</item>
</style>
```

Comment: or use TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small/Large

Comment: If it replaces both res/values/styles.xml and res/values-v21/styles.xml, where did you put this XML?

Comment: Same issue faced! but this is real strange my app wasn't targeting lollipop nor my project had any folder res/values-21. The framework is supposed to pickup styles from res/values-v14 when the app run on Lollipop.

Comment: The correct style popupMenu is `<item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_panel_holo_dark</item>` and you can find *menu_panel_holo_dark* in `sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable`

Comment: and for divider add this `<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/popupMenuListViewStyle</item>`  `<style name="popupMenuListViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
         
         <item name="android:divider">@drawable/list_divider_holo_dark</item>
         
     </style>`